# Unity Lenses Missing (files/folders, applications)

Tags: unity, lenses

The File & Folders lens and default Applications lens is missing from my dock. How can I get them back?

I attempted the guide here: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/how-to-reset-unity-launcher-icons-or.html

All the icons came back except the two missing lenses. unity-place-applications and unity-place-files are both currently installed.

Comment: Do you have .desktop files for both in `/usr/share/unity/places`? Have you tried reinstalling the packaged (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-place-files unity-place-applications`)?

Comment: there is an applications.place file and a files.place file in that location.

Comment: @htorque  Your solution worked for me -- maybe make it an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Make sure you have those packages installed:

  ```
  unity-lens-applications
  unity-lens-files
  ```
- Make sure you have those two files in `/usr/share/unity/lenses`:

  ```
  applications.lens
  files.lens
  ```
- If it still doesn't work, try to reinstall the two packages:

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files
  sudo apt-get install unity-lens-applications unity-lens-files
  ```
- If it still doesn't work, I suggest [reporting a bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug):

  ```
  ubuntu-bug unity # if unity is the wrong package, others will fix it
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure how common this problem is anymore, but I just did a bare bones install of Ubuntu 12.10 and couldn't find anything in the Dash. It seems the unity-place-applications and unity-place-files packages have been replaced by unity-lens-applications and unity-lens-files, respectively - just in case anyone else comes across this.