# "More Apps" icon disappered on launcher. How can it be restored?

Tags: 11.04, unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity Lenses Missing (files/folders, applications)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43096/unity-lenses-missing-files-folders-applications)

I know how to add icons for applications to the launcher; but the icon lost is for "More Apps".  I don't know what is the application responsible for "More Apps".  Could someone provide help?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the package `unity-place-applications` installed and that the file `/usr/share/unity/places/applications.place` exists.

Answer (score 0):

@htorque:  Thanks for your reply.  I can confirm that the package unity-place-applications existed before the "More Apps" icon disappeared.  However, it happened that the icon returned after a reboot of the system.  Further observations reveals that the "More Apps" icon disappeared every time after I made changes to compiz effects; but on reboot the icon returned.