# Is there a Unity Lens to replace the filemanager

Tags: unity, filemanager

I'm setting up Ubuntu for a couple who have very little knowledge of computers in general.

Instead of making them open nautilus to find their family photos and videos, is there an already made unity lens where the photos and videos can be browsed via the dash, and the filter options be the name of particular folders rather than "file types" or "date accessed" and "file size" ?

Comment: Well using File manager isn't that hard is it? AFAIK, there aren't any lens that are so functional. Lens are supposed to supplement the file managers. Not to replace them.

Comment: It's for an elderly couple. Ubuntu runs fine on it, and I could teach them to use nautilus, but it would be so simple for them if they could just have to click on the unity button, and browse their family photos and videos from there.

Comment: I understand your motive. Unfortunately, I don't think the current lens have those features you seek. :/

Comment: How about keeping a shortcut for shotwell on the unity bar and ask them to open the app from unity. Shotwell imports the pics from whichever folder you configure it for and will infact help the couple to browse through the pics based on the time line..

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Something like Shotwell that would also make thumbnails for videos would also be good. The less apps to use the better in this particular case. If all else fails, I'll stick to just placing folders on the desktop, with single click opening

Comment: There is a shotwell lens but after just trying it the filters are not all that useful compared to tags/events in shotwell.

Comment: Does not unity-lens-files package satisfy you? Check the discussion here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/43096/unity-lenses-missing-files-folders-applications

Answer (score 1):

I'm finding Ubuntu Files to be very slow (Ubuntu seems slow in general).  From what I've gathered it doesn't utilize an index.  One workaround is to install the Recoll indexing app, and add 'unity-scope-recoll' from a ppa.  This allows terms to be tested against the index and displayed in the lens.

Recoll
http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/

scope
https://bitbucket.org/medoc/unity-scope-recoll

Comment: Recoll scope works great.  It displays matched email items right in the lens instantly, as I type.  Also, once I disabled the online search results under the 'security' settings, Ubuntu began to feel snappy.  I'm really looking forward to this being improved.

Answer (score 0):

If filenames are meaningful or you remember the name of the folder they are stored in, I think the usual File lens works fine and it would be very easy to handle even from elderly people. Using just that lens to navigate your files you don't have to care where are stored your files as long as you remember their names